# Django admin with many to many choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following `models.py` and `admin.py` files. The intention is to allow for selection of multiple categories for a given product if necessary.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brief = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descrip = models.TextField(max_length=1300)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Product_Category')

class Product_Category(models.Model):
    cats = {"AUT":"Automation", "PWA":"Personal Wealth Advisory", 
            "BCH":"Blockchain", "LOS":"Loan Origination", "FX":"Foreign Exchange"}
    choices = tuple((human, c) for human, c in cats.items())
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choices)
```

**admin.py**

```
 from .models import Product, Product_Feature, Organization, Product_Category

class PFeatureInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Product_Feature
    extra = 1

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    logo_file = forms.ImageField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        logo_file = self.cleaned_data.get("logo_file", None)
        self.instance.logo = b64encode(logo_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
        return forms.BaseModelForm.save(self, commit=commit)

    class Meta():
        exclude = ["logo"]
        model = Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
    inlines = [PFeatureInLine,]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(Organization)
```

This results in the following, when accessing a `Products` object through admin:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you need to display like this?

[image]

I suggest you to use `FilteredSelectMultiple`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

from .models import Product, Product_Feature, Organization, Product_Category


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    logo_file = forms.ImageField()

    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
          queryset=Product_Category.objects.all(),
          required=False,
          widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
              verbose_name=_('Categories'),
              is_stacked=False
          )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['categories'].initial = self.instance.categories.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        logo_file = self.cleaned_data.get("logo_file", None)
        self.instance.logo = b64encode(logo_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
        return forms.BaseModelForm.save(self, commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['logo']
        model = Product


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
    inlines = [PFeatureInLine,]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got the FilteredSelectMultiple widget, however it's not showing any of the defined categories, it's again blank. See here: https://i.imgur.com/Va3Ihz5.png

Comment: ah ok. so i need to make one of each of the categories? any idea how to change the display here so that it's the name of the category rather than `Product_category object` : https://i.imgur.com/l7kjMbo.png

Comment: you should create `def __str__(self): return self.name` for python3 or `def __unicode__(self): return self.name` for python2, inside class of class `Product_Category` in the `models.py`

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. does this mean that any time i add a new category i need to make an instance of that category first before it will be considered available for the filter widget?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is buried in the comments under the accepted answer.

For Many2Many the available items are not primarily defined by `choices` but by the records in the joined table. In your case, the `product_category` table needs to be populated with those 5 choices.

It's a little frustrating that `makemigrations` can't handle this for you but oh well.