# how to show a manytomany django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to do that a user can modify his/her profile.

[image]

At the rigth (in the image attached in url) we can see that the user has coins and wallets (Bitcoin, Ethereum and coinbase)

The goal is that in the left form, the user could change his/her data and add or remove coins and wallets.

I need:

1. How can I do that with **ModelMultipleChoiceField**?
2. How can I show the user's data in the input when the form is loaded?. e.g: antonigalile will be un name input

I would like that my widget looks like that:

[image]

Here my files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_fee = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    market_cap = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    circulating = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    change = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
    change_password_code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(default=now)
    wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    avatar = models.CharField(blank=True,default="bitcoin.png",max_length=15)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9,blank=True)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12,blank=True)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        exclude = ()
    wallets = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all(),to_field_name="name")
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    two_factors_auth = forms.BooleanField()
    coins = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Coin.objects.all(),to_field_name="name")
```

**form.html**

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
         <p> {{ edit_profile_form.name.label }} </p>
         {% render_field edit_profile_form.name class+="form-control" %}
         {{ edit_profile_form.name.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p> {{ edit_profile_form.email.label }} </p>
         {% render_field edit_profile_form.email class+="form-control" %}
         {{ edit_profile_form.email.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p>My Wallets</p>
         {{ edit_profile_form.wallets}}
         {{ edit_profile_form.wallets.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <p>My Coins</p>
         {{ edit_profile_form.coins }}
         {{ edit_profile_form.coins.errors }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <p>Activate two factor authentication
        {{ edit_profile_form.two_factors_auth }}</p>
        {{ edit_profile_form.two_factors_auth.errors }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="profileButton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

**views.py** (no finished)

```
class userPageView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'user.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['edit_profile_form'] = EditProfileForm(prefix='contact')
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'user.html')
```

¿What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: does *Look like the [django one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz1tr.png)* means create a new instance in that ModelMultipleChoiceField by clicking the `+` plus button, like in Django admin form?

Comment: Not really, like that: http://mc706.com/static/img/django-permissions-widget.PNG

Comment: @AntoniCobos might this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45265299/6396981

Comment: @SancaKembang It doesn't work to me, I have two m2m fields and the example has only one, I don't know where I should to put the "solution" code in forms.py? in admin.py?